# Can Vagrant use Hyper-V server as a provider?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, vagrant

Can Vagrant be used to provision Virtual Machines using Hyper-V server, such as Hyper-V server 2012 or 2016?

Our lab has Windows licenses for guests, so since Vagrant already has support for Hyper-V on the desktop, I figured it would be able to provision hypervisor version as well.

A example of this sort of provisioning is the vagrant-vsphere plugin, that allows a machine running Vagrant to provision vSphere machines over a network.

Comment: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/

Answer (score 0):

No, support for Server 2012 is not working at the time of writing and is the subject of a bug report [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7391)